# PHP not working in Apache when site directory is symlink from remote mount

Tags: php, apache, symlink

Apache 2.4.6, Centos 7, PHP 7

In an attempt to share file system across aws instances, I moved a site directory from `/home/site1` to `/efs/home/site1` - preserving file permissions and hidden files (`cp -rp /home/site1/. /efs/home/site1`)

After moving, the original directory was deleted and a symlink created from `/efs/home/site1` to `/home/site1`.

Now, all static files like txt, html & jpg files are working normally, however, **PHP will not work**.

When PHP files are accessed, it throws 500 Internal Error.

The above setup works in nginx php-fpm web server but not in Apache! Any idea what could cause this issue?

EDIT

```
[centos@ip-150-25-50-1 ~]$ sudo ls -alZ /home/site1/public_html
lrwxrwxrwx site1 site1 ?     /home/site1/public_html -> /efs/home/site1/public_html

[centos@ip-150-25-50-1 ~]$ sudo ls -alZ /home/site1/public_html/dir1
drwxr-xr-x site1 site1 ?                   .
drwxr-x--- site1 site1 ?                   ..
-rw-r--r-- site1 site1 ?                   123.jpg
-rw-r--r-- site1 site1 ?                   345.png
-rw-r--r-- site1 site1 ?                   index.php
drwxr-xr-x site1 site1 ?                   subdir1
```

Comment: Any chance you can check the log for the exact error? Maybe http://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks will help?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, tried suggestions in the link but did not work. No errors found at: tail -n 10 /var/log/httpd/error_log There were no php error file generated in the site directory.

Comment: why don't you change the home directory in your apache config instead of making a symlink

Comment: httpd.conf has so many links to /home/site1/... I tried changing them all to /efs/home/site1/... still it will not work. But moving only public_html & symlinking from remote works. No need to edit http.conf

Comment: I am wondering if this is an issue with `selinux` which is enabled by default on C7. Can you [edit] in the output of `ls -alZ` on a directory that has some php and png files? In addition to the symlink itself, this might better help us diagnose.

Comment: Output from ls -alZ has been added. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Moving /home/site1/fcgi-bin & symlinking from remote breaks PHP. Solution is to symlink all but fcgi-bin.